# JQuery .on AJAX events fired multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm currently working on a Rails application that fires an AJAX request when a form is clicked. The request is sent successfully only one time, but the following JQuery event is triggered a seemingly arbitrary number of times (anywhere from 1-15). Basically, there's one AJAX request, many AJAX events being logged. This is causing the comment being returned to get inserted multiple times.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(function () {
        //target comment-form from comment form partial
        $(document)
            .on("ajax:beforeSend", '.comment-form-div', function (evt, xhr, settings) {
                console.log("Ajax request sent")
                return $(this).find('text_area')
                    .addClass('uneditable-input')
                    .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            })
            .on("ajax:success", '.comment-form-div', function (evt, data, status, xhr) {
                console.log("Ajax request successful")

                $(this).find('text_area')
                    .removeClass('uneditable-input')
                    .removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled')
                    .val('');
                $(this).hide('slow')
                return $(xhr.responseText).hide().insertAfter($(this)).show('slow');
            });
    });
});
```

For reference, here is the Rails form in the html:

```
<div class="comment-form-div" id='master-comment-form'>
    <%= form_for(comment, remote: true) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= f.text_area :body, :placeholder => "Add a comment" %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :commentable_id, value: comment.commentable_id %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :commentable_type, value: comment.commentable_type %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: You've got a "ready" handler wrapped in another "ready" handler ...

Comment: How do you bind the click event to the form?

Comment: ^ Rails built-in helpers (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#built-in-helpers). The issue isn't the click event, however. It's the AJAX event.

Comment: I'm also curious to see how you're triggering the "ajax:beforeSend" event. How is it bound? My guess is that therein lies the problem

Comment: It's bound in the code given to the document. Then the selector (http://api.jquery.com/on/) .comment-form-div is passed in to bind it to the form only. The reason for this is that the response of the AJAX request inserts more comments that may also generate their own forms. So binding to the document and then filtering through forms ensures that the AJAX request is always handled. I just can't figure out why beforeSend is getting called anywhere between 1-15 times for each ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't hijack ajax:beforeSend neither ajax:success, just put your business logic (javascript) into update.js.erb

You can write some "console.log('ajax:success fired!')" if you want to check when this is fired though.

Comment: The response is already the partial containing the comment. I don't see how moving the JS as a response would cause anything different to occur.